# Accessing key value pairs in a hash within a hash with Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, hash, rspec

I'm writing a test against a API XML response that I converted to a hash. The hash however is nested so it seems to behave like "Offer" is the key and everything else is the value. (Shown below)

I would like to be able to access the key-value pairs within this hash so I can assert using rspec tests against "Id", "Count" etc. Thanks

```
{"Offer"=>
  {"href"=>"http://xyz",
   "links"=>nil,
   "Id"=>"1501507",
   "Count"=>"5",
   "Collected"=>"3",
   "Status"=>"INPROGRESS"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also `#dig` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

```
hash = {
  "Offer"=> { 
    "href"      => "http://xyz",
    "links"     =>  nil,
    "Id"        => "1501507",
    "Count"     => "5",
    "Collected" => "3",
    "Status"    => "INPROGRESS" 
  } 
}

puts hash.dig("Offer", "href")
# => http://xyz
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If

```
hash = { "Offer"=> { "href"      => "http://xyz",
                     "links"     =>  nil,
                     "Id"        => "1501507",
                     "Count"     => "5",
                     "Collected" => "3",
                     "Status"    => "INPROGRESS" } }
```

Then you can use this sort of notation:

```
hash["Offer"]["href"] #=> "http://xyz"
```

Or define a new hash and use regular hash access:

```
new_hash = hash["Offer"]
new_hash #=>
# { "href"      => "http://xyz",
#   "links"     => nil,
#   "Id"        => "1501507",
#   "Count"     => "5",
#   "Collected" => "3",
#   "Status"    => "INPROGRESS" }

new_hash["href"] #=> "http://xyz"
```

Comment: Thanks a million I was just about to delete this as I found the answer but I will leave it others.